# Testing methods exposed through react context

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-context, react-testing-library

I have a react context like this

**UserContext.js**

```
export const UserContext = createContext({
    createUser: async () => {
      ...execute some xhr requests and manipulateData
    },
    getUser: () => {},
  });

  const UserProvider ({ children }) => {
    const context = {
      createUser,
      getUser,
    };

    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={context}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

And the following unit test

**UserContext.spec.js**

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import UserProvider, { UserContext } from '@my-contexts/user';
...

let createUser = () => {};
render(
  <UserProvider>
    <UserContext.Consumer>
      {value => {
        createUser = value.createUser;
        return null;
      }}
    </UserContext.Consumer>
  </UserProvider>
);

await createUser(data);

expect(data).toEqual({ status: 200 });
```

I am not sure if this way

```
let createUser = () => {};
render(
  <UserProvider>
    <UserContext.Consumer>
      {value => {
        createUser = value.createUser;
        return null;
      }}
    </UserContext.Consumer>
  </UserProvider>
);
```

it is the better technique for "extract" the inner methods exposed in the `UserContext` (in this case `createUser` method)

In my App code I use this context like following:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from '@my-contexts/user';

const someComponent = (props) => {
   ...
   const { createUser } = useContext(UserContext); 
   const handleCreate = (e) => {
     createUser(form);
   };
   return (
     <form>
         <label>Username</label>
         <input value={form.userName} /> 
         <button type="submit" onClick={handleCreate}> create user </button>
     </form>
   )
};
```

But the problem is that I can get the exposed methods from context only if I have a component and get the method using `useContext` hook.

If I want to test the `createUser` method in isolation:

**Exists a better way for get the methods exposed in context without  rendering a provider and consumer and "manually extract" him?**

Comment: The proper way would be to create some mock consumer component, and assert changes on that component while invoking functions from your context. Or, you're just misusing react-testing-library.